# POST request with textfields and files

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm following this [tutorial](https://makitweb.com/how-to-upload-multiple-image-files-with-jquery-ajax-and-php/) on how to upload files with ajax and php. However this is only for image attachments alone while my form is a mix of text fields and attachments. I have no problem uploading text fields alone.

This is my HTML for attachments:

```
<!-- Attachments -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1" style="background-color: #fff;"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
          </div>
        <input type="submit" class="form-control" value="Add Attachment" id="addAttachment">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Upon clicking on Add Attachment:

```
var attachmentCounter = 0;
$("#addAttachment").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (attachmentCounter == 0) {
        $(this).after('<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple><br>');
        attachmentCounter = attachmentCounter + 1;
    }
});
```

And when submitting the form, this is the code:

```
$("#applyLoan").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // There are some variable declarations here that I just skipped because I think they aren't relevant to the question

    var applicationFormData = {
        LoanType: loanType,
        LoanPurpose: loanPurpose,
        Principal: principal,
        Term: term,
        PaymentMode: paymentMode,
        Interest: interest,
        Penalty: penalty
    }

    // Additionals
    var formData = new FormData();
    // This is the form text fields
    formData.append('applicationFormData', JSON.stringify(applicationFormData));

    // These are the images
    var totalfiles = document.getElementById('files').files.length;
    for (var index = 0; index < totalfiles; index++) {
        formData.append("files[]", document.getElementById('files').files[index]);
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/application_form.php",
        data: formData,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

application_form.php

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
    if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
        echo "Files set";
    } else {
        echo "Files not set";
    }
}
```

I get an error on the opening tag of the ajax request:

```
  jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
     at i (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
     at qt (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
     at Function.k.param (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
     at Function.ajax (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
     at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (application_form.js:219)
     at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
     at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
```

Comment: You didn't follow the tutorial carefully. You left out the `processData: false` and `contentType: false` options.

Comment: @Barmar There is no longer any error showing but I get no response from my PHP file. I've added the PHP code above

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `contentType: false` and `processData: false` to send FormData with jQuery ajax.

`contentType` option will set Content-Type header automatically, and `processData` option force jQuery to convert your FormData to String, which is not possible.

so your Ajax source code will be:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/application_form.php",
    data: formData,
    enctype: "multipart/form-data",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: I've already tried that but I get no response from my PHP file `application_form.php` is posted above EDIT: It seems that I had  `dataType: 'json'` too. I removed it and now get the response.

Comment: I don't get a response when doing if `(isset($_POST['LoanType']) && isset($_POST['LoanPurpose']) && isset($_POST['Principal']) && isset($_POST['Term']) && isset($_POST['PaymentMode']) && isset($_POST['Interest']) && isset($_POST['Penalty'])) { echo "Test"; }` but I get a response with `(isset($_POST) { echo "Test"; }` I need the parameters though

Comment: @e700867 You need to post applicationFormData with each params, not with stringified text. try something like: `Object.keys(applicationFormData).forEach(x => { formData.append(x, applicationFormData[x]); });` rather than `formData.append('applicationFormData', JSON.stringify(applicationFormData));`